# Missing listener.ora file

Tags: oracle, powerbi, odac

I'm attempting to make a connection to an Oracle Database with Microsoft Power BI Desktop.

Originally I was getting the following error message:

> "The recommended provider ('Oracle.DataAccess.Client') is not
>   installed. You can continue with your current provider, however it has
>   been deprecated and may not work properly."

I've installed Oracle Database Access Components (ODAC), specifically "64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64" from [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).  The message no longer appears.  However, I now get a second error after attempting to connect to a database (which I can connect through Oracle's SQL Developer with no issues):

> **Unable to connect**
>
> We encountered an error while trying to connect.
>
> Details: "Oracle: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener"

After install, there doesn't seem to be a "listener.ora" file located in %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\ folder at all.  I do see "sqlnet.ora" and "tsnames.ora" but nothing else.  Did I install the proper application or am I missing something?  I tried doing a search of the file on the computer but nothing came up.  Thanks.

Comment: You don’t need a listener on your PC to access a database as a client, which is what ODAC is going to do? The listener runs on the database server, and that has a listener.ora. Did you install the right thing? We don’t know what you want to do....

Comment: @AlexPoole let me edit my question to be a bit more detailed

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having the problem see this Power BI Desktop Help page.

Manage your data Source - Oracle [Power BI Desktop Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem-manage-oracle)

```
 Oracle Client --> [ Oracle Listener on Database Server --> Oracle Database Username ]
```

The Oracle Listener is normally located on the Oracle Database Server.  Each Oracle Database running on the server will register Service Names with the Oracle Listener.

Oracle database initialization parameter `local_listener`

```
local_listener (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
```

- The local_listener is on the database server, the localhost port 1521.

> The Oracle Client Networking Description Files are:
>   
>   
>  [Oracle Home Directory]\Network\Admin\sqlnet.ora
>   
>  and 
>   
>  [Oracle Home Directory]\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora
>   
>   
>  See the sqlnet.ora line [ NAME.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT) ]
>   
>   
>  *Default is TNSNAMES.*
>   
>  TNSNAMES reads the description from the tnsnames.ora file.
>   
>   
>  Add your tnsnames description to the tnsnames.ora file. Use the CONTOSO connection description below as a guide.

- Check with the Database Administrator, for HOST, PORT and the database SERVICE_NAME parameters.
- Use the Oracle **tnsping** command to check the connection description.

> tnsping CONTOSO
>   
>   
>  ***CONTOSO*** = (DESCRIPTION =
>   
>   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **oracleserver.contoso.com**)(PORT = **1521**))
>   
>   (CONNECT_DATA =
>   
>    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>   
>    (SERVICE_NAME = **CONTOSO**)
>   
>   )
>   
>  )
>   
>   
>  Please remember that this is for the Power BI Desktop.
>   
>   
>   *If you plan to move your Power BI Project to a Cloud Services or to a Local Power BI reporting server, check with your Server Administrator for connection information.*